# How to generate items from an item in a Flux (Spring Reactor)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

How can I model below scenario with a reactor Flux?

```
  +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
  |       |        |       | -----> |       |
  |   A   | ---->  |   B   | -----> |   C   |
  |       |        |       | -----> |       |
  +-------+        +-------+        +-------+
```

`A` generates items received by `B` that from that item will emit `[0..N]` items to be received by `C`.

How to write the Flux so that `B` can emit new items based on the items emitted by `A` ?

```
A a = ...
B b = ...
C c = ...

Flux.push((emitter) -> a.run(emitter))
 .howToMapOneEelementToMany((emitter, item) -> b.handle(emitter, item); // ???
 .doOnNext((item) -> c.handle(item))
 .subscribe();
```

---

EDIT: Example

- `A` produces paths to Excel files
- `B` reads the the Excel file and produces an item per row (can be **a lot** of rows or none)
- `C` stores each row in a database

Comment: maybe .thanMany?

Comment: FlatMap? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @sfiss interesting, how can that be used without knowing how many new items will be created e.g. can it be used with `Flux.push` or similar ?

Comment: Its not really clear as to what you are asking, because your code example doesn't really match what you are asking for. you write `produces an item per row` but then you have a written `howToGenerateManyItemsFromOneItem` <-- thats not one item per row

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Good spot, I think the example better describes what I want to do

Comment: i think this blogpost will give you the answers you need https://simonbasle.github.io/2017/10/file-reading-in-reactor/

Answer (score 1):

If you have many files, so is already a Flux. You could just do a flatMap, with this, for each item of the Flux will be generate another flux of rows.
There are another methods if you want maintain the order of data like concatMap and flatMapSequential.

```
 public Flux<String> someMethod() {

    return Flux.fromIterable(List.of("excelFileData", "excelFileData2"))
      .flatMap(this::getRows);

  }

  private Flux<String> getRows(String file) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(file.lines().collect(toList()));
  }
```

See the reactor documentation, is pretty good.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

But if you want transform a Mono to a flux you could do something like this:

```
public Flux<String> someMethod() {

  return Mono.just("excelFileData")
    .flatMapMany(this::getRows);

}

private Flux<String> getRows(String file) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(file.lines().collect(toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By recommendation of @sfiss `flatMap` seems a good candidate

```
ExcelFilePathReaderSink pathReader = ...
ExcelRowHandlerSink rowHandler = ...
OutputWriter outWriter = ...

Flux.push(pathReader)     // A
  .flatMap(rowHandler)    // B
  .doOnNext(outWriter)    // C
  .subscribe();
```